# Implementing predicates but resulting in 1 fetchedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am having some difficulty getting results from CoreData after implementing Predicate. The implementation only results in 1 fetchedObject and I dont know why.

```
class PhotoAlbumViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

var pin: Pin!

lazy var context: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.stack!.context
    }()

lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult> = {
        let fetchedRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Photo")
        fetchedRequest.sortDescriptors = []
        fetchedRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "pins == %@", argumentArray: [self.pin])
        return NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchedRequest, managedObjectContext: self.context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    }()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Unable to perform fetch: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    let fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    print(fetchedObjects.count) //returns 1 only

}
```

Both Photo entity and Pin have a relationship with each other.

Any advice here is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You'll need sortDescriptors as Apple recommended.

Comment: I suspect only one object matches the predicate.

Comment: Why do you need a predicate?

Comment: Predicate useful for searching! If you want to fetch all of the data? Remove it, use sortDescriptors instead

Comment: Is "pins" a to-many relationship? Then you perhaps want `NSPredicate(format: "ANY pins == %@", self.pin)`

Comment: From what I understand, you will get all Photos objects that contain exactly one reference - the reference to your pin and only that. You could try a the IN operator; `%@ in pins`

Comment: How is this related to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982276/swift-coredata-fetchobjects-only-return-1-item-after-implement-predicate?

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! Your question actually prompted myself to check on the relationship. Pins to Photos was suppose to be a one-to-many relationship which i missed out when i was setting up my model. Now it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Pins to Photos was suppose to be a one-to-many relationship. I missed this portion out when I was setting up the models, setting it as a one-to-one relationship. After amending it with a new model version it worked correctly.